# Bootstrap adding what appears to be a two pixel margin between adjacent divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question that I believe pertains to the Bootstrap framework.  Whenever I import bootstrap it looks like it makes two adjacent divs have a 2 pixel margin between them, although nothing in the element inspector suggests what could be causing this.  Removing the very first line in the linked fiddle makes the spacing go away.  Would anybody be able to tell me what causes this spacing?  Again, I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this from using the element inspector.  I'm basically looking at the spacing between the red and the green divs. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

HTML

```
<div class="row"><div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">DIV1 DIV1</div>
  <div id="second">DIV 2 DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
#first {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
}
#second {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 0 0 302px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsulli99/ngapjysq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap. Bootstrap has a solution to your problem. It uses a grid system through which you can display your content. Gird system consist of desktop, tablets and mobile grid system. You can use a 12 grid  col-md-12. or 4 gird col-md-4 or 1 grid col-md-1. The best thing about this is you do not need to worry about CSS. Bootstrap takes care of it.  You could use col-md-offset to bring divs close to each other. http://www.bootply.com/DCJ2m2Qitm  full width grid pattern without space between div http://www.bootply.com/KImM5xvufe

try this code.

```
<div col-md-5>
  <p>This is First Gird</p>
</div>
 <div col-md-5>
  <p>This is Second Gird</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand the bootstrap grid system, however these particular divs are actually for content, not high-level layout per se.  I actually want the div elements touching each other, for example if I want to create a checkerboard-style pattern with varying background colors.

Comment: I have edited my link to bootply. Let me know if that is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: Actually this is what I am looking for.  I am confused because I thought offset was to actually put a 'space' of x columns by moving the column over as described here. http://getbootstrap.com/css/.  I am surprised this actually works (based on what I know, but at first glance it looks like it does).  I will do some testing if this works I will send you $10 via paypal and approve your answer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: sure. check out my another bootply link. for full width grid pattern.   Thanks for your quick approval to my answer. :)

Comment: You are officially the man.  Let me know where you want me to send that $10.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.$10 not required buddy. Thanks for the offer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform you of what is happening to your code, as of bootstrap v3, bootstrap adds `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to blocks for `box-sizing:border-box;`

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is done for "easier sizing options and an enhanced grid system" and will keep the width of your div at the specified width and not add an extra pixel to the left and right as you expected it would.

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Thank you for adding to this answer user336572.  I have to admit that although I've made a lot of headway on learning the funky art of CSS :before and :after is something to me that is skill kind of black boxy to me.  Anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to help me.